# Place X items in N matrices without repeat column and row

Tags: algorithms, search, matrix

I have *N* matrices (*n* × *m*) and items to place in each one (*n* · *m*). The same items are repeated randomly for each matrix. When one item is placed in (*i*, *j*), for the following matrices the item cannot be placed in the same row or column.

> *For example:*
>
> A 3 × 3 matrix is repeated 3 times. We have 9 items (**A**, **B**, …, **I**). In the first step, I add **A** randomly to the matrix 1 to the position (1, 2). Now with the second matrix, **A** cannot be placed in column 1 or row 2, they need to be excluded from the randomly selected positions.

Is there a known algorithm I can use for this or what solutions can you propose?

Comment: You could just rotate the rows and columns, but that wouldn't make the individual matrices very “random”.

Comment: what do you mean with rotate rows and columns? remember that you can have N repetitions of the matrices. Also I need to randomize

Comment: That means if you put A in (1,2) then in the 2nd grid it goes to (2,3) and in the 3rd in (3,1).  To produce the 2nd grid, move each row down 1 row and move the last row to the top, then do the same for the columns.  Repeat for the subsequent grids.  This works as long as N<=n and N<=m.  But assumes all grids have the same number of each element.

Comment: this is a very simple and easy solution. The only missing would be have a more random distribution.

Comment: Maybe you should better specify your requirement for "randomness".

Comment: This appears to be known as a 'derangement' of the elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895/shuffle-list-ensuring-that-no-item-remains-in-same-position

Answer (score 1):

What I've meant with my comment was the following simple algorithm.

> Let *n* ∈ **N** and *V* = {1, …, *n*} be your set of items. To generate *n* × *n* matrices *M*<sup>(1)</sup>
>   , … *M*<sup>(*n*)</sup> with the desired property, pick the elements of *M*<sup>(1)</sup> randomly from *V* without repetition. Then generate *M*<sup>(*i* + 1)</sup> by rotating the rows and columns of *M*<sup>(*i*)</sup>.

By *rotating the rows* of matrix *M* I mean that the elements of the old row *i* become the elements of the new row *i* + 1 and the elements of the old row *n* become the elements of the new row 1. *Rotating the columns* happens likewise.

Illustrated by example:

```
 A B C                                     G H I
 D E F     -----  rotate rows  ----->      A B C
 G H I                                     D E F

   |
 rotate
 columns
   |
   V

 C A B
 F D E
 I G H
```

I have implemented a quick version of this in C++.

```c++
int
main()
{
  constexpr auto N = std::size_t {3};
  std::array<char, N * N> items;
  std::array<square_matrix<char, N>, N> matrices;
  auto rndeng = std::default_random_engine {std::random_device {}()};
  std::iota(std::begin(items), std::end(items), 'A');
  std::shuffle(std::begin(items), std::end(items), rndeng);
  std::copy(std::begin(items), std::end(items), std::begin(matrices.front()));
  for (auto& matrix : matrices)
    {
      matrix = matrices.front();
      rotate_rows(matrices.front());
      rotate_cols(matrices.front());
    }
  assert(is_valid(items, matrices));
  for (const auto& matrix : matrices)
    std::cout << matrix << '\n';
}
```

Where the acceptance criterion is defined in `is_valid` like this

```c++
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
bool
is_valid(const std::array<T, N * N>& items,
         const std::array<square_matrix<T, N>, N>& matrices)
{
  for (const auto& item : items)
    {
      std::array<std::size_t, N> at_row;
      std::array<std::size_t, N> at_col;
      for (auto idx = std::size_t {}; idx < N; ++idx)
        {
          const auto at = find_item(matrices[idx], item);
          if (at == std::make_pair(N, N))
            return false;
          at_row[idx] = at.first;
          at_col[idx] = at.second;
        }
      for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < N; ++i)
        {
          if (std::count(std::begin(at_row), std::end(at_row), i) != 1)
            return false;
          if (std::count(std::begin(at_col), std::end(at_col), i) != 1)
            return false;
        }
    }
  return true;
}
```

using the following helper function `find_item`.

```c++
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto
find_item(const square_matrix<T, N>& matrix, const T& item)
{
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < matrix.rows(); ++i)
    {
      for (auto j = std::size_t {}; j < matrix.cols(); ++j)
        {
          if (matrix(i, j) == item)
            return std::make_pair(i, j);
        }
    }
  return std::make_pair(matrix.rows(), matrix.cols());
}
```

The code for `rotate_rows` and `rotate_cols` is given here.

```c++
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void
rotate_rows(square_matrix<T, N>& matrix)
{
  for (auto j = std::size_t {}; j < matrix.cols(); ++j)
    {
      const auto temp = matrix(matrix.rows() - 1, j);
      for (auto i = std::size_t {matrix.rows() - 1}; i > 0; --i)
        matrix(i, j) = matrix(i - 1, j);
      matrix(0, j) = temp;
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void
rotate_cols(square_matrix<T, N>& matrix)
{
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < matrix.rows(); ++i)
    {
      const auto temp = matrix(i, matrix.cols() - 1);
      for (auto j = std::size_t {matrix.cols() - 1}; j > 0; --j)
        matrix(i, j) = matrix(i, j - 1);
      matrix(i, 0) = temp;
    }
}
```

Finally, I'm using the following simple `square_matrix` type.

```c++
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class square_matrix final
{
 private:

  std::array<T, N * N> data_;

 public:

  std::size_t rows() const noexcept { return N; }
  std::size_t cols() const noexcept { return N; }

  T&
  operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j)
  {
    assert((i < this->rows()) && (j < this->cols()));
    return this->data_[i * this->rows() + j];
  }

  const T&
  operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j) const
  {
    assert((i < this->rows()) && (j < this->cols()));
    return this->data_[i * this->rows() + j];
  }

  auto begin() { return this->data_.begin(); }
  auto end() { return this->data_.end(); }

  auto begin() const { return this->data_.begin(); }
  auto end() const { return this->data_.end(); }

};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const square_matrix<T, N>& mat)
{
  for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < mat.rows(); ++i)
    {
      for (auto j = std::size_t {}; j < mat.cols(); ++j)
        os << ' ' << mat(i, j);
      os << '\n';
    }
  return os;
}
```

If you want to make the result less predictable, you can additionally shuffle the generated matrices after you're done.

Comment: shuffling matrix is an important part of this solution

Answer (score 0):

There are (n x m)! permutations of the elements, which we can assign an index to each:

```
1, 2, 3, ..., (n x m)!
```

For example if we have a 2 x 2 matrix, we will have (2 x 2)! or 24 permutations:

```
 1. A B C D
 2. A B D C
 3. A C B D
 4. A C D B
 5. A D B C
 6. A D C B
 7. B A C D
 8. B A D C
 9. B C A D
10. B C D A
11. B D A C
12. B D C A
13. C A B D
14. C A D B
15. C B A D
16. C B D A
17. C D A B
18. C D B A
19. D A B C
20. D A C B
21. D B A C
22. D B C A
23. D C A B
24. D C B A
```

So all we need to is to randomly select (without replacement) N of these permutations, one per matrix. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1) for ideas on how to do this.

Once you have selected your permutations indices, say (1, 18, 23) for N=3, you can then find the corresponding permutations as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others).

Comment: It does not take into account the no repeat column and row condition right?

Comment: Yes you're right.